# select different cell values reside inside the single row of dynamic html table

Tags: asp.net, web

Hi I am new to programming and this is my first question in stackoverflow.
Please forgive If I have made any mistake while posting this question.

I want to achieve functionality that shown in below HTML table

[Output HTML table and selection of values as highlited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99SZG.png).

If I select more than one cells corresponding to any row I can only select other remaining cells in that row, at the same time I cant select any other cell residing in other row.

Also If I select single cell from a row I can select any other cell from different row. now in this case previous selection will be disabled.

basically I want to restrict multiple row cell selection if I select more than two cells in a row by using shift key randomly.

below is my code to create HTML table.

```
function buildIPTGrid(iptView) 
{
    var firstValue = '';
    var secondValue = '';

    $("#IPTResults").empty();
    $("#IPTVolumes").empty();

    var pIPTGrid = "";

    var pIPTVolumesGrid = "<ul id='iptRateGrid'>";

    pIPTVolumesGrid = pIPTVolumesGrid + "<li><strong>Rates</strong><br/></li></ul>";
    //var pIPTGrid = "<ul id='iptGrid'></ul>";

   // pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<li><strong>Rates</strong><br/></li>";

    pIPTGrid = "</br>" + pIPTGrid + "<table id='priceTable'><tr><th class='dpTdHeaderData'><span> Type </span></th><th class='dpTdHeaderData'><span> Delivery Type</span></th>";

    $(iptView[0].NymexRates).each(function (index, obj) {
        pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<th class='dpTdHeaderData'><span style='text-align:center;'> " +
            concatMonthYear(iptView[0].NymexRates[index].rateMonth, iptView[0].NymexRates[index].rateYear)
        + "</th></span>";
    });

    pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";
    pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr><th class='dpTdHeaderData'><span></span></td><td><span></span></th>";
    for (var i = 1; i < iptView[0].NymexRates.length + 1; i++) {
        pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<th class='dpTdHeaderData'><span style='text-align:center;'>" +
            i + "</span></th>";
    }

    pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";
    //index NYMEX
    pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr><th class='dpTdHeaderData'><span> NYMEX </span></th><th><span> </span></th>";

    $(iptView[0].NymexRates).each(function (index, obj) {
        pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<td class='dpTdNormal'><span style='text-align:center;'> " +
            iptView[0].NymexRates[index].rateFixed + "</td></span>";
    });
    pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";

    //END index NYMEX

    //Avg index NYMEX
    pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr><th class='dpTdHeaderData'><span>Avg Wt NYMEX </span></th><th><span> </span></th>";

    $(iptView[0].AverageNymexRates).each(function (index, obj) {
        pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<td class='dpTdNormal'><span style='text-align:center;'> " +
            iptView[0].NymexRates[index].rateFixed + "</td></span>";
    });
    pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";
    //End Avg index NYMEX

    //Firm Type 
    for (var i = 0; i < iptView[0].Rates.length; i++) {

        switch (iptView[0].Rates[i].firmType) {
            case 1:
                firstValue = "1F";
                secondValue = "GC Fixed";
                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateFixed);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";

                firstValue = " ";
                secondValue = "GC Basis";
                pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid =  BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateBasis);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";

                break;
            case 2:

                firstValue = "4F";
                secondValue = "BT Fixed";
                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateFixed);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";

                firstValue = " ";
                secondValue = "BT Basis";
                pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateBasis);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";
                break;
            case 6:

                firstValue = "2F";
                secondValue = "GC Fixed";
                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateFixed);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";

                firstValue = " ";
                secondValue = "GC Basis";
                pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateBasis);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";
                break;
            case 7:

                firstValue = "5F";
                secondValue = "BT Fixed";
                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateFixed);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";

                firstValue = " ";
                secondValue = "BT Basis";
                pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateBasis);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";
                break;
            case 8:

                firstValue = "3F";
                secondValue = "GC Fixed";
                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateFixed);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";

                firstValue = " ";
                secondValue = "GC Basis";
                pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateBasis);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";
                break;
            case 9:

                firstValue = "6F";
                secondValue = "BT Fixed";
                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateFixed);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";

                firstValue = " ";
                secondValue = "BT Basis";
                pIPTGrid + "<tr>";
                pIPTGrid = BuildHeaderData(pIPTGrid, firstValue, secondValue);

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    if (iptView[0].Rates[index].firmType == 1) {
                        pIPTGrid = BuildIPTPriceData(pIPTGrid, iptView[0].Rates[index].rateBasis);
                    }
                });

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";
                break;

            case 0:
                //Interruptible 
                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr><th class='dpTdHeaderData'><span> Interruptible (CG) </span></th><th><span> </span></th>";

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<td class='`'><span style='text-align:center;'> " +
                        iptView[0].Rates[index].rateFixed + "</td></span>";
                });
                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";

                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<tr><th class='dpTdHeaderData'><span> Basis (CG) </span></th><th><span> </span></th>";

                $(iptView[0].Rates).each(function (index, obj) {
                    pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "<td class='dpTdNormal'><span style='text-align:center;'> " +
                        iptView[0].Rates[index].rateBasis + "</td></span>";
                });
                pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</tr>";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        i = i + iptView[0].NymexRates.length;
    }
    //End Firm Type

    //pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</label></li>";

    pIPTGrid = pIPTGrid + "</table></br>";

    $("#IPTVolumes").append(pIPTVolumesGrid);
    $("#IPTResults").append(pIPTGrid);
    $("#IPTVolumes").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#IPTResults").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#CreatePGPB").css("visibility", "visible");
}
```

Also I need to find the selected cell value is in which month (as shown in table header) and whether it is fixed or basis.

Comment: there is vast amounts of repetition in this code which could be avoided with better use of variables. The switch statement in particular repeats itself hugely. In the case statements you could just assign the variables that actually change as a result of the case, and write the actual processing code (which never varies, apart from case 0 which can be dealt with separately) once after the switch ends (or in a separate, re-usable function). As it is, there's so much noise in here that it's really hard to understand what's going on. Consider re-factoring it and then editing the question.

Comment: Thanks ADyson. I know that the code is garbage itself, I will work on the same to reduce repetitive code. but I need the attached image like multiple cell value selection restricting to single row only. How will I achieve this.

Comment: "multiple cell value selection restricting to single row only". I have really very little idea what you mean by this. You want the user to be able only to make certain selections with the mouse? For what reason? What happens after they make the selection? Anyway I don't think it's possible - I don't know of any API that lets you control what the user highlights on screen.